# iptables eth0 wlan0 bridge not working

Tags: linux, iptables

I am trying to allow an embedded system to share the wireless of my laptop. The embedded system is an [A20 Olinuxino Micro](https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A20/A20-OLinuXino-MICRO/open-source-hardware) running Debian and my Laptop has Ubuntu 12.04.

I tried this which has worked on different systems in the past:

On my laptop:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# iptables -F 
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE 
# iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT 
# ifconfig eth0 192.168.10.1
```

On the Olinuxino:

```
# ifconfig eth0 192.168.10.10
```

Similar configurations have worked well for me in the past but in this instance I can't get internet access on the Olinuxino even though I can ping 192.168.10.1 fine. I am not sure on how to proceed in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Have you tried pinging the outside world from your embedded system?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also tell Olinuxino how to talk to anything past `192.168.10.1`:

On the Olinuxino:

```
route add default gw 192.168.10.1 eth0
```

You might also need to configure DNS servers for the Olinuxino box.